# POST request with data specified in text file via CURL?

Tags: php

I have a simple CMS based on css,HTML and PHP witout DB. I made a cURL script to update the content, including templates (mix of text and HTML) via POST.

```
curl_setopt ($upload, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
```

and &postfields:

```
$postfields["person"] = "Kris";
$postfields["action"] = "Update";
$postfields["page"] = "Name of the page";
$postfields["newcontent"] = $post;
```

+

```
$post=file_get_contents("update.txt");
```

What I need is to send via POST **data specified in text file** (update.txt) including a mix of html/css/php.I don't want to upload a single file just POST its content
Any idea? :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Updated using questions field names and setting Mimetype for file

According to [Send a file via POST with cURL and PHP](http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/) and the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS) you do the following:

```
    $file_name_with_full_path = realpath('update.txt');

    $postfields = array('person' => 'Kris',
        'action' => 'Update',
        'page' => 'Name of the page',
        'newcontent'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path.';type=html');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;
```

Comment: Just tried this and cURL posted single world "Array" instead of <!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head> (...)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted :)

```
$postfields["newcontent"] = $post;
```

+

```
$newcontent = 'post.txt';
$post = file_get_contents($newcontent);
```